# How size of virtual memory is decided and calculated in Linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

How is the size of virtual memory decided and calculated in Linux? What will be size of virtual memory for 32bit/64bit system?

Answer (score 2):

The size of the virtual address space depends upon the operating system.

The hardware sets the underling size of the logical address space (2^32 or 2^64 bytes). The size of virtual memory will usually be less than those limits dictated by:

1. Division of the address space into kernel and user areas
2. System Parameters
3. Process quotas
4. Page file space

Answer (score 1):

Virtual memory can be any size, it can be larger than the available physical memory, if need be. If you don't understand why this is the case, then you need to learn up more about virtual memory. However, the virtual address space **typically** will be the same size as the physical address space. That means that on a 32-bit system, both virtual and physical memory will be 4GiB large. The difference would be that **each program** has access to their own 4GiB virtual memory, and paging + swapping will be used to ensure that the memory of one user program cannot be accessed by other user programs.

To get a more detailed understanding about how paging is implemented in Linux, you can read through the [Paging section on OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging).

Answer (score -1):

The size of virtual memory is also depends on the processor  , how much of address space can be address by processor , it  is  simple for  32 bit  it is  4gb and for 64 bit  it is 2^64.